# email not sent in cronjob sugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I have set email settings using gmail from my localhost successfully and my sugar instance is sending test mail well. I also done with cron job setup and tested it.
 The problem occurs when i try to send email in a cron job it cannot be send. My basic code i am using is

```
    require_once('include/SugarPHPMailer.php'); 
    $emailObj = new Email();
    $defaults = $emailObj->getSystemDefaultEmail();
    $mail = new SugarPHPMailer();
    $mail->setMailerForSystem();
    $mail->From = $defaults['email'];
    $mail->FromName = $defaults['name'];
    $mail->Subject=from_html($bean->name);
    $mail->Body="hello this is testing ....!";
    $mail->prepForOutbound();
    $mail->AddAddress('abc@yahoo.com'); 
    @$mail->Send();
```

The following errors  displayed in fatal log .

```
09/24/12 10:58:07 [4560][1][FATAL] SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server. Code: , Reply: 
09/24/12 10:58:07 [4560][1][FATAL] SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server. Code: , Reply: 
09/24/12 10:58:07 [4560][1][FATAL] SMTP -> ERROR:AUTH not accepted from server. Code:  Reply: 
09/24/12 10:58:07 [4560][1][FATAL] SugarPHPMailer encountered an error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
09/24/12 10:58:07 [4560][1][FATAL] SugarPHPMailer encountered an error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
09/24/12 10:58:07 [4560][1][FATAL] SugarPHPMailer encountered an error: An outgoing mail server is not configured to send emails. Please configure an outgoing mail server or select an outgoing mail server for the mail account that you are using in Settings >> Mail Account.
```

Some time it give follwing one,

```
  09/24/12 11:01:07 [832][1][FATAL] SugarPHPMailer encountered an error: Language string failed to load: tls
```

can anybody help please?

Comment: Can you confirm the system email settings are set properly? Looks like somehow they are not.

Comment: yes email settings was set, i confirmed by sending a test mail.

Comment: Are you seeing any PHP errors in here? I'm thinking somehow the default email settings are being loaded somehow.